# Уведомление клиента при изменении объекта другим клиентом

Tags: java, swing, desktop

Есть Java desktop приложение на Swing, которое работает с БД.
Появилась необходимость при изменении объекта одним клиентом, изменить этот же объект на другом клиенте.

Подскажите в какую сторону технологий можно копнуть?

Comment: Объекта какого в БД или в коде?

Comment: обмен данными идет только через БД? Соответственно и работать через БД.

Comment: @Александр Мартынцев объект в java созданный из БД.  К примеру данные из таблицы, пользователь поменял данные, я сохранил в таблицу и хочу, чтоб другой клиент без обновления получил новую откорректированную запись.

Comment: @Tachkin да, только через БД, то есть нужно городить свою систему для уведомления?

Comment: [вот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618915/how-to-implement-a-db-listener-in-java) на заграничном сайте обсуждение имплементации листенеров на ДБ

Answer (score 1):

Используйте для рассылки уведомлений шину сообщений, например библиотеку [mbassador](https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador). Она позволяет отправлять сообщения как асинхронно, так и синхронно. В месте, где объект изменяется - отправьте в нее эвент сообщение, а там, где надо это отследить - сделайте подписку на него. Это одна из практик реактивного программирования, которая позволяет удобно и гибко реагировать на события не прибегаю к патерну Listener.

Comment: прочел и не могу понять если подписка и уведомление находятся на одном компьютере, то все понятно.  А если приложения на разных, нужно поднимать свою точку взаимодействия?

Comment: Если на разных - то конечно. В таком случае необходимо реализовать клиент-серверное приложение, если БД одна, а клиентов много, то сервер должен с ней взаимодействовать, а уже клиенты получать от него команды об изменении тех или иных объектов бизнес-логики, но опять же, на самом клиенте при получении от сервера события, ни кто вам не запрещает упаковать его в событие и отправить в шину.